# What is the difference between a "Weakly increasing variables" and "not being a decreasing variable"?

Tags: computer-science, finite-state-machine

I was reading subsection [5.4.6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBjBN.jpg) about state machine derived variables in [Mathematics for Computer Science](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-042j-mathematics-for-computer-science-spring-2015/readings/MIT6_042JS15_textbook.pdf), after defining weakly/strictly increasing and decreasing variables, this was in the footnote.

> Weakly increasing variables are often also called nondecreasing. We
>   will avoid this terminology to prevent confusion between nondecreasing
>   variables and variables with the much weaker property of not being a
>   decreasing variable.

so what is the difference between a "Weakly increasing variables" and "not being a decreasing variable"? and what is decreasing variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about the specific context, but something is usually called decreasing if it *always* goes downwards. That means something is "not decreasing" if it ever happens at some point that it goes upwards. However, something is nondecreasing (or weakly increasing) if it *never* goes downwards. That's a much stronger demand.

Said differently, something is "nondecreasing" if it never decreases, while it is "not decreasing" as long as it doesn't always decrease.